# G-d's name on screen readers

Tags: halacha, technology, shemos-sacred-names, see-sight-vision-blind, hearing

People who are blind or hard-of-seeing often interact with computers using devices called "screen readers".  These screen readers will read aloud the words that are written on the screen (or in the part of the screen the user cares about).

I don't know how screen readers pronounce the Tetragrammaton, but I assume it depends on the software (and I assume that it is not properly).

Are there any halakhic issues that can come of this?

Possible issues:

- Can you write out the Tetragrammaton somewhere it will be read by a screen reader? (proxied speaking)
- Can you write the Tetragrammaton *in order to* have it read by a screen reader? (intentional proxied speaking)
- Can you use a screen reader when you visit a website that has the Tetragrammaton? (hearing)

Comment: http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/aud/5773-Halacha/5773-27_mechikas_hashem.mp3 see this shiur by rabbi nissan kaplan

Comment: Is this question assuming pronouncing the Tetragrammaton is forbidden? It may want to make that assumption explicit.

Comment: @msh210 An answer that brings sources that say there's no issue whatsoever because there's no problems pronouncing the Tetragrammaton would be a fine answer.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman to add to what `@msh210` said, is there a reason to assume that "**you** shall not pronounce his name in vain" (lo sisa es shmo lashav) applies to any-one/thing other than a jew?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight not that I know of. As I said, "no problems whatsoever" is a perfectly fine answer (and the answer I'd expect)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman its difficult to answer that something isnt a problem if there is nothing to rule it against (i.e. can you point as you read the torah v.s. do i have to be afraid of scratching the letter's)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Perhaps a better but less specific version of this question is: `What methods of pronouncing the Tetragrammaton are forbidden?  Can I listen to a live radio show where It is being said?  Can I cause a machine to make Those Sounds? Can I cause a non-Jew to speak It?  Can I audiate It?`

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31732/limits-of-pronunciation-of-the-tetragrammaton