# Limits of pronunciation of the Tetragrammaton

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, hearing, shemos-sacred-names

What methods of pronouncing the Tetragrammaton are forbidden?

1. Can I listen to a live radio show where It is being said?
2. Can I cause a machine to make Those Sounds?
3. Can I cause a non-Jew to speak It?
4. Can I [audiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audiation) (aurally imagine) It?
5. Can I move my mouth in such a way that would I expel breath, the Name would be said?